# Solr Elevation Component not working

Tags: solr

Following is my configuration as per https://wiki.apache.org/solr/QueryElevationComponent

```
<searchComponent name="elevator" class="solr.QueryElevationComponent" startup="lazy">
    <!-- pick a fieldType to analyze queries -->
    <str name="queryFieldType">string</str>
    <str name="config-file">elevate.xml</str>
  </searchComponent>

  <!-- A request handler for demonstrating the elevator component -->

  <requestHandler name="/elevate" class="solr.SearchHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="last-components">
      <str>elevator</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>
```

The query to achieve the elevation was

```
$HOST/solr/collection/elevate?q=*:*&wt=json&elevatedIds=34464
```

But I don't see the document id of 34464 to be elevated.Can anyone please point out my mistake?

Comment: Is `34464` the Solr id? What is your version of Solr?

Comment: Did you try with `forceElevation` parameter?

Comment: My version of solr is 5.2.0 and yes I did try with forceElevation parameter.34464 is the document ID.Am i doing it correct?

Comment: You have to use the id created by Solr and not the id that you defined yourself for your doc? Is this what you do?